# Remove certain numbers python

Tags: python, numbers

I understand how to get rid of certain text, but when it comes to numbers, it clashes with other numbers in it.

```
def get_team_odds(soup):
    for i in soup:
        soup_output = (i.get_text())
        bleach_characters = soup_output.lstrip("Value")
        return(bleach_characters.replace("for",""))
```

This gives an output of 0.57  10  0.

I need to get rid of the 10 and the 0. However if I use `replace` or `strip`. It also gets rid of some numbers from the 1st one. So if the output is 10.07, it would give me .7, because it gets rid of all 10's and 0's. How do I get rid of certain numbers based on position or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your string into a list of substrings. For example:

```
x = '0.57 10 0'

#separate the space delimited string into a list containing substrings
y = x.split(' ')

#you can access an element from your list
print y[0]

#or all of the elements
for i in y:
    print i
```

Comment: Thank you, I used: words = new_chars.split(' ')
      return words[0]. Worked perfectly

Comment: Glad i could help. Please up vote my response if your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on the logical segments of the output string, not the characters as `replace` does:

```
output = ' '.join(x for x in output.split() if x not in ('10', '0'))
```

This will also normalise whitespace, so if that's not OK for you, something more sophisticated is needed.

Comment: Thanks, its the split part I didn't understand, now I know :D

Comment: List comprehension will add unnecessary overhead and complexity to this task. The split('regex') function contains all the functionality described in the original question.

Comment: I don't understand your comment on several accounts. First, I don't use list comprehension. The argument to `join` is a generator expression which doesn't build a list in memory, so there's no overhead. Second, the `split` in your answer doesn't use regular expressions but simple character matching. And third, regular expressions are widely considered more complex than solutions that don't rely on them (even though that's not necessarily my own opinion). Also, I don't understand why your usage example converts to `int` just before printing where conversion back to string is done anyway.